# Getting an error when trying to use postgres typeorm Raw method

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

can anyone help me with this?

I'm having a error when trying to search in postgres with typeorm. I'm trying to pass a Raw where, but I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": "column \"mm\" does not exist"
}
```

This is my code where I use Raw:

```
const appointments = await this.ormRepository.find({
    where: {
        date: Raw(
            dateFieldName =>
            `to_char(${dateFieldName}, MM-YYYY) = '${parsedMonth}-${year}'`,
        ),
    },
});
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: you've told Postgres that `MM` is a column (thus the error). Instead of `MM-YYYY`, use `'MM-YYYY'`.

Comment: Thanks so much man, it really solve my problem, I'm following a course and they use it without the quotes, maybe this changed!

Comment: I doubt the syntax changed: I guessing your course writers made a mistake. Wouldn't be the first time!